# Error running builder 'javascript validator'

Tags: javascript, eclipse, javabuilders

I have problem on building my workspace.

I get this errors

> Errors occurred during the build.
>   Errors running builder 'JavaScript Validator' on project

I already tried un-ticking  builders -> JavaScript Validator, but the problem is that the .js file. I tried to open it, but only using Text Editor not JavaScript Editor.

is there any solutions aside from unticking?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Opening of .js files in text editor or validation errors.

Comment: if i untick the javascript validator the error does not occur but I could not open it using javascript editor only text editor... only 1 file is affected other files are ok